# Rails 3.1 escape_javascript doesn't work as expected in Rails 3.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Working with Rails 3.0, if one wanted to render some partial through javascript (in an AJAX call for example), one would escape the content like so

```
$('#some_id').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@post) %>');
```

and it would work, because `escape_javascript` escaped line breaks, quotes, and similar.

In Rails 3.1, the same method is escaping everything (including `<` for example), making it impossible for me to render content. Has this changed in 3.1? How do you do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably on Rails 3.1.0.rc2 which was just released. There is a bug in `escape_javascript` that was fixed right after the release (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1553) but is not in a published release yet. 
In the mean time, you can either revert to 3.1.0.rc1, or you can add an initializer to your project with the following:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper
  def escape_javascript_with_workaround(javascript)
    escape_javascript_without_workaround(javascript.try(:to_str)).html_safe
  end

  alias_method_chain :escape_javascript, :workaround
end
```

**UPDATE:**

[Rails 3.1.0.rc3 was released today](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/8/ann-rails-3-1-0-rc3-has-been-released) which fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually on 3.1.0rc2 :D